# Error getting JSON and trying to parse it [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I´ve been looking at this the entire day, looking other solutions but nothing, I can´t solve my problem.

I want to get the JSON of https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global, parse it so I can extract the username and in a future other attributes like post, avatar...
This is my `viewDidLoad` where I set up the connection with the URL and then I change it to NSData Object.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                      URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *timeline= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                          options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSDictionary *user;
for(int i=0; i<[timeline count];i++)
{
    user = [timeline objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Statuses: %@", [user objectForKey:@"username"]);
}
```

My program starts running and then it stops. I know when it stops`(user = [timeline objectiAtIndex:i])` but I have no idea why... Another question: Would `[user objectForKey:@"username"]` be enough to extract the usernames?

Comment: Have you learned about the difference between a synchronous and an asynchronous request yet?

Comment: If you are using synchronous requests you have to make sure that they don't run in the applications main thread. You may want to check the apple documentation for asynchronous requests: [NSUrlConnection Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeline data is contained in a dictionary which can be accessed through the key "data". I would do something along the lines of:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                      URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray *timelineArray;

if (responseObject) {
    timelineArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSDictionary *user; // user data

    for (NSDictionary *status in timelineArray) {
        user = [status objectForKey:@"user"];

        NSLog(@"Status: %@", [status objectForKey:@"text"]);
        NSLog(@"Status by user: %@\n\n", [user objectForKey:@"username"]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would probably also add some additional checks for errors in the response, missing keys, etc. in production ready code.

Comment: Your answer works. It still prints all the statuses as null, but that is something related with extracting the usernames correctly from the JSON, and i guess i will figure it out during the day! Thank you!

Comment: @iOSAddicted, I added some additional print outs (the status text as well as the user who made it), hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome. Thats all that i need! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: is it possible also to extract the avatar and store it as a UIImage?

Comment: @iOSAddicted, I'd do something like this: https://gist.github.com/nmock/6bfe09af8758acd2d1b3

Comment: I found another way similar to yours, the problem is that both methods don't work correctly. It´s true that both methods extracts the url from the avatar_image, but when I run my app the screen is completely black. If i assign the UIImageView to a local image, it loads correctly, but when we talk about load all the avatars from the JSON the Simulator just shows a black screen.

Ignore the answer, it loads but it takes a loooooooong time to load.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because the following line returns an NSDictionary, not an NSArray.

```
NSArray* timeline= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

So it should be,

```
NSDictionary* timeline= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

and your logic should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I changed what you said. The problem is now, when i try to print the user, returns null :S
    NSDictionary *user;
    for(int i=0; i<[publicTimeline count];i++)
    {
        user = [publicTimeline objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"Statuses: %@", user);
    }

Comment: The data structure itself is much more complicated than your code lets on. You're assuming that there is a "username" directly in the timeline, and that's not the case. It's buried deeper in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the web service is returning a JSON dictionary as opposed to an array. This would cause an unrecognized selector exception to throw on `[timeline objectAtIndex:i]`. Print out what the request returns in the debugger, and if it's a dictionary you'll need to find how to access the array you are expecting before iterating.

Comment: The requests just returns the url:https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global

Comment: The very, very first character that the URL returns is a { . JSON either contains a dictionary { } or an array [ ]. Yours contains a dictionary. Assigning the result to an NSArray* doesn't make it an array. Either get the spec for the API that you are using, or you'll have to reverse engineer it, which isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing logic is incorrectly assuming that timeline will be an NSArray when the structure of the data you are retrieving indicates that it will actually be an NSDictionary.